# C - Check that an int read by scanf is in the range of the integers

Tags: c, int, range

I have got this code that reads an integer using scanf and checks if it is actually an integer by looking at the buffer.

```
int e_1; 
char c[1];
// noNeedToCleanBuffer is used to avoid buffer cleaning the first time.
int noNeedToCleanBuffer = 1;
do {
    // Clears the buffer.
    if (!noNeedToCleanBuffer)
        while ((c[0] = getchar()) != '\n') ;

    noNeedToCleanBuffer = 0;
    printf("Input an integer value: \n");
    e_1 = scanf("%d", &n);  

    c[0] = getchar();
} while ((e_1 != 1 && c[0] != 10) || (e_1 == 1 && c[0] != 10));
```

However I cannot figure out how to check if the input is between INT_MIN and INT_MAX (I get these from limits.h).

I was thinking of getting the number as a string and compare it with two strings that would represent INT_MIN and INT_MAX, but since I am using the standard c99 I am not allowed to use atoi() or itoa().

Comment: You can use `strtol()` and such, that's in C99..

Comment: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtol.3.asp

this would convert it to a long int and not to an int.

thanks anyway

Comment: What's wrong with it being a `long`? You can then easily check the `long` against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, as `long`s are always larger (or equal to) `int`s, and you can use `strtol()` to do the error handling in case of things that don't even fit in a `long`. Also, note that `atoi()` (but not `itoa()`) _are_ in C99, but it doesn't do error checking.

Comment: long is larger than int depending on what machine I am running the program. so I cannot rely on that.

Comment: No, `long` is larger or equal to `int` on _all_ conforming implementations. `2 <= sizeof(int) <= 4 <= sizeof(long)`. This is guaranteed by the standard (actually, IIRC the standard specifies it in bits and not bytes, but that's irrelevant to this discussion). So you can use this approach portably.

Comment: Exactly! it can be equal...so what would happen if it's so? A long would have the same range of an int and I would not be able to test that a number is within an int range.

Comment: Not a problem, check out the [strtol() documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) - if an integer overflow or underflow occurs, `strtol()` will return `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN` respectively, and `errno` will be set to `ERANGE`. Note that you should set `errno` to `0` before calling `strtol()` in order to reliably detect errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to check store it-

1.)Store in long and then check

2.)Store the number in string then convert the INT_MAX into a string by getting each digit and storing in string and then using strcmp()

```
num = INT_MAX;
i = 0;

while(num != 0){
    str[i] = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    i++;
}
```

The number would be opposite in this string you can get it reversed quite easily by a simple loop

Then use strcmp();

Comment: 1. long does not have a wider range of acceptable inputs than int, except than in some machines.

2. this could work, but I was wondering if there is a function that does the conversion and it's allowed to be used under c99

Comment: @sic2 i dont really see any problem with the string method

Comment: I just thought this could be expensive, but I just realized that the time complexity is O(log(n))

Comment: Do accept the answer by clicking on the check button in left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `s` conversion specifier with `scanf` to read the string and use `strtol` function to check the number.

- `strtol` let you first check if number is in the correct format (an integer) and if it is representable as a `long` integer
- Then check the `long` number is between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Sir , if i have an unsigned int and i using scanf try to store more than range of it, what will happen ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of a variable that is of any given data type (including `int`) will always be within the range of that data type.  This is defined and enforced by the platform for which the application is compiled.

If you just want to go through an exercise of "proving" that the variable is within the bounds of your type, you have to cast it to a variable of such a type that can accommodate a greater range of values.  For example:

```
int foo = /* some value to test */;
long bar = (long)foo;

if ( (bar < (long)INT_MIN) || (bar > (long)INT_MAX) ) return false;
```