# input of higher number than allowed for int type

Tags: c

I'm checking my code with different inputs. I have for example the next code:

```
if((scanf("%d",&n)!=1)) {
  printf("Invalid number\n");
  return 0;
}
```

if i'll try to scan a higher number of `int` than allowed (for example: 10000000000), it won't print "Invalid number". I want it to print and end the program. what to do?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007600/detecting-integral-overflow-with-scanf

Comment: You could use a long and then check if the long is within the int bounds. Or you could use a string.

Comment: @interjay.: I missed the part...it reads the number but as it overflown then the number will be something unexpected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438954/c-check-that-an-int-read-by-scanf-is-in-the-range-of-the-integers

Answer (score 0):

Number of read items would be `1` but as int would not be able to hold the value it would hold something other than what is entered. Because 32 bit signed int(most likely the case) won't be able to hold that number. As a result it will contain some garbage value.